# Combinatorics Through Guided Discovery Question 77

Tags: combinatorics, induction, recursion

I need help with a homework question. Thank you in advance!

```
 Suppose that f is a function on the nonnegative integers such that f(0) = 0 and f(n) = n+f(n−1). 

 (A) Prove that f(n) = n(n+1)/2. Notice that this gives a third proof that 1 + 2 + · · · + n = 
 n(n+1)/2, because this sum satisfies the two conditions for f. (The sum has no terms and is thus 0 
 when n = 0.) 

 (B) Also find a formula if f(0)=3.
```

(A): I believe the induction portion for part A goes as follows:

```
We prove the formula for f by induction on n. If n = 0, then n(n+1)/2=0.

Assume that f(k-1) = ((k-1)k)/2

Then, 
f(k) = k + f(k-1)
f(k) = k + ((k-1)k)/2
f(k) = k(k+1)/2

Therefore, the truth of the formula for n=k-1 implies its truth for n=k and thus by the principle of 
induction, the formula for f holds true for all nonnegative integers n.
```

(B): I'm not too sure how to find the formula, but I know it has to be recursive. Once a closed formula is found, then it has to be proved with induction. Any tips for finding a formula for f(0)=3 would be appreciated for this part!

Comment: Try:  $3 + (n)(n+1)/2$

Answer (score 1):

Your part (A) is basically correct. My only point is that when you state your assumption that $f(k-1) = \frac{(k-1)k}{2}$, you should also state it's for some $k \ge 1$.

As for part (B), note $f(1) = 1 + f(0) = 1 + 3$, $f(2) = 2 + f(1) = 2 + 1 + 3 = (2 + 1) + 3$, $f(3) = 3 + f(2) = 3 + (2 + 1) + 3 = (3 + 2 + 1) + 3$, etc. I assume you see a pattern here, which I'll leave to you to finish. However, [dodoturkoz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/804253/dodoturkoz)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033836/combinatorics-through-guided-discovery-question-77#comment8329256_4033836) already states the result for you.

Comment: (+1) Maybe I shouldn't have stated it directly, but I knew someone would explain it much more clearly :)